# Проблемы при использовании forms.FloatField

Tags: python, django

Всем привет.

Написал простейшее приложение по расчету индекса массы тела.
Все работает нормально, до определенного момента, а потом начинает появляться ошибка

> "ValueError at / The view indexmassi.views.indexmassi didn't return an
>   HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Решается только заменой строк с POST строками с насильно указанными значениями веса и роста. Тогда страница отображается норм и потом возвращаю обратно.

Закономерность выявить не могу. Обычно раз в 4-6 часов такая фигня, только вот работало, жму <kbd>F5</kbd> и всё. Сегодня вот переустановил систему, запустил проект и сразу вылезло.

views.py такой:

```
from django.shortcuts import render 
from .forms import Forma


def indexmassi(request):
     if request.method == "POST":
        forma = Forma(request.POST)
        ves = float(request.POST.get("ves"))
        rost = float(request.POST.get("rost"))
        im = round(float(ves/((rost * rost) / 10000)), 1)
        if 1 <= im < 16:
            opisanie = "Выраженный дефицит массы"
        elif 16 < im <= 18.5:
            opisanie = "Недостаточная масса тела"
        elif 18.5 < im <= 25:
            opisanie = "Вы нормальный"
        elif 25 < im <= 30:
            opisanie = "Избыточная масса тела (предожирение)"
        elif 30 < im <= 35:
            opisanie = "Ожирение 1-ой степени!"
        elif 35 < im <= 40:
            opisanie = "Ожирение 2-ой степени!"
        elif im > 40:
            opisanie = "Ожирение 3-ой степени!"
        else:
            opisanie = "Некорректный результат!"
        return render(request, 'indexmassi/index.html', {"forma": forma, "message": format(im), "opisanie": opisanie})
```

Answer (score 0):

твоя функция не вернет объект HttpResponse в том случае если метод не POST (request.method != 'POST'), добавь в конце просто редирект на index-страницу:

```
def indexmassi(request):
     if request.method == "POST":
        forma = Forma(request.POST)
        ves = float(request.POST.get("ves"))
        rost = float(request.POST.get("rost"))
        im = round(float(ves/((rost * rost) / 10000)), 1)
        if 1 <= im < 16:
            opisanie = "Выраженный дефицит массы"
        elif 16 < im <= 18.5:
            opisanie = "Недостаточная масса тела"
        elif 18.5 < im <= 25:
            opisanie = "Вы нормальный"
        elif 25 < im <= 30:
            opisanie = "Избыточная масса тела (предожирение)"
        elif 30 < im <= 35:
            opisanie = "Ожирение 1-ой степени!"
        elif 35 < im <= 40:
            opisanie = "Ожирение 2-ой степени!"
        elif im > 40:
            opisanie = "Ожирение 3-ой степени!"
        else:
            opisanie = "Некорректный результат!"
        return render(request, 'indexmassi/index.html', {"forma": forma, "message": format(im), "opisanie": opisanie})
    return redirect('indexmassi/index.html')
```

Comment: Надо еще библиотеку redirect было подключить. Не робит так. Он пытается попасть на адрес http://127.0.0.1:8000/indexmassi/index.html и пишет Page not found (404)
Сама страница у меня в урлах так привязана  path('', include('indexmassi.urls'))

Я пока решил проблему так:
    else:
        forma = Forma(request.POST)
        im = 0
        opisanie = "Некорректный результат!"
        return render(request, 'indexmassi/index.html',
                      {"forma": forma, "message": format(im), "opisanie": opisanie})